# Let $f:T→ \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following question...

Let $f:T→ \mathbb{R}$  be a function.

Let $K \subseteq T, D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $K \subseteq f^{-1}(f(K)) $ and $f(f^{-1}(D)) \subseteq D$.

This is what I was thinking...

Let $x \in K$. Then $x \in T$ and hence $f(x) \in f(K) \subseteq f(T)$. Since  $f(x) \in f(K)$ then $x \in f^{-1}(f(K))$. Therefore, for any $x \in K$, $x \in f^{-1}f(K)$. So, $k \subseteq f^{-1}f(k))$.

Now suppose $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in f(f^{-1}(D))$. Then there exists $y\in f^{-1}(D)$ such that $x = f(y)$. Since $y \in f^{-1}(D)$ then $f(y) \in D$. Similarly, since $x = f(y)$ then $f^{-1}(x) = y$. Thus $f(f^{-1}(x)) \in D$, but $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$. Therefore, $x \in D$ and thus, $f(f^{-1})(D)) \subseteq D$.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, so is this how I would prove these/are there corrections I should make?

Comment: In your second proof, you conclude that $f(y) \in D$, and you already know that $x = f(y)$, so you can immediately jump to $x \in D$. In fact, it is incorrect to go the long way around, because to say $f^{-1}(x) = y$ requires that the inverse of $f$ be well defined, which is not guaranteed. The first proof is correct.

Comment: So if I change the second proof to say... Now suppose $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in f(f^{-1}(D))$. Then there exists $y\in f^{-1}(D)$ such that $x = f(y)$. Since $x = f(y)$ then $x \in D$ and thus, $f(f^{-1})(D)) \subseteq D$. Then is that I all have to show to prove it?

Comment: You still need to justify why $f(y)$ is in $D$, but then you're done

Comment: You still need to show that $f(y)$ is in $D$ before you can conclude that  $x$ is in $D$. This should be no problem at all; you gave correct justification in your original question. "Since $y \in f^{-1}(D)$ then..."

Comment: Yes, that would justify it. The reason why you can conclude $f(y) \in D$ right there is because that is the definition of the preimage of $D$

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now, so the correct proof would read... Now suppose $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in f(f^{-1}(D))$. Then there exists $y\in f^{-1}(D)$ such that $x = f(y)$. Since $y \in f^{-1}(D)$ then $f(y) \in D$. Since $x = f(y)$ then $x \in D$ and thus, $f(f^{-1})(D)) \subseteq D$.

Comment: That is a correct proof, perfect.